# Execute a function from an uploaded file

Tags: django, django-file-upload

I have a site, where I want to run a code from an uploaded file from every 2 hours. So the user can upload many files and choose which one is the active. After the two hours, I check the database for 'active' files, and I want to import that file, and run a method from that file.

Here's the model, which stores the uploaded files:

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='myApp/files/uploaded_files')
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

How can I call a method from that file?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your question - but this can easily be abused; please proceed with extreme caution.

Comment: Are you really being serious? Have you thought security wise how dangerous this will be?

Comment: Yeah, I'm serious. Only the admins will be able to upload any files, and choose wich one is the active.